# When I go into the "solid" viewport shading option everything turns into a glitchy fuzz on my screen ( I think reshade is messing it up)

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

When I go into the "solid" viewport shading mode it  goes very pixely, like the glitch pixels. I don't think this has happened to anyo[image]ne else and I don't know but reshade might have something to do with. I've tryed every single way of deleting it, even deleting all my blender files and reinstalling it a hundred times but the reshade splash screen won't go away and it crashes instantly. Someone please help or I don't think i can keep using blender.

Comment: I don't know anything about Reshade. But what about this error message in red on top of the screen? **"Unable to save current preset. Make sure you have write permissions to C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\ReShadePreset.ini."**

Comment: It's the reshade splash screen. Even if I delete all the files, even in the app directory it won't disappear